# Passing argument in make command

Tags: python, makefile

I have a target in the makefile called 'data' (taken from [cookiecutter](https://github.com/drivendata/cookiecutter-data-science/blob/master/%7B%7B%20cookiecutter.repo_name%20%7D%7D/Makefile)) and I am trying to pass an argument to this target which is calling a file like this:

```
## Make Dataset
data: requirements
    $(PYTHON_INTERPRETER) src/data/make_dataset.py
```

I want to pass some arguments to this make target so they can be captured by the make_dataset.py file and used in main.

The part I tried in make_dataset.py looks like:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--cg', default='scope', help= "some help")
def main(cg):
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue? I want to use this make target like:

```
make data --cg=xyz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how `make` works. What you ask is typically done by declaring a variable in the `Makefile` which you can then override from the command line.

```
CGFLAGS=

## Make Dataset
data: requirements
    $(PYTHON_INTERPRETER) src/data/make_dataset.py $(CGFLAGS)
```

Now if you pass in `make CGFLAGS='--cg=xyz' data` the value of the variable you specified in the command line will explicitly be interpolated into the `data` recipe.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
CG:=
CG_OPT:=$(addprefix --cg=,$(CG))

data: requirements
    $(PYTHON_INTERPRETER) src/data/make_dataset.py $(CG_OPT)
```

And then do:

```
make data CG=xyz
```

Notice that $(CG_OPT) will be blank if you do not specify a `CG=...` on the make command line.  Unfortunately using variable names that start with `--` can confuse things, though it can be done as well:

```
 --cg:=
 data: requirements
    $(PYTHON_INTERPRETER) src/data/make_dataset.py $(addprefix,--cg=,$(--cg))
```

But then, to prevent make from interpreting the `--cg` as an internal make option, you have to add a `--` option before it on the command line as follows:

```
 make data -- --cg=xyz
```

Note: this all assumes you want to do a specific variable name `--cg=`.   If you wanted it to work for any variable name, you would have to do something similar to what @tripleee suggested